# How to formalize axioms in the Isabelle proff assistant?

Tags: isabelle

I have a few axioms that involve iterate over a set for example:
[axiom with and](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s2ykA.png).

My question is how can I write this in Isabelle. I am using the Pure framework and I have been writting the other axioms using the axiomatization command.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you have a reason not embed your new logic in HOL?

Comment: Not really. Someone sugested to me to follow the way FOL was formalized that's way I went this way. How could have I embeded it in HOL?

Comment: For example: https://www.isa-afp.org/browser_info/current/AFP/FOL-Fitting/FOL_Fitting.html does an embedding in HOL: you define symbols usually in a datatype (here Forall), then a semantics (here eval). Finally you prove theorems (here correctness).

Comment: The embedding is necessary to reason *about* the logic, while the logic in Pure is necessary to reason *in* the logic. No sure what you want.